# Azure Batch OutputFiles upload from all compute nodes

Tags: azure, azure-batch, azure-sdk-python

I have a mpi-based task, where each thread writes files on 'working-directory' for each compute node on Azure-Batch.

The task is configured to upload result (files) to my storage account.

But only the files on the master node are uploaded to storage.

I want to know,

how can I make all the nodes to upload files to my storage account ?

Is there any intermediate way to copy the files on to the files from the slave nodes to the master node and upload to storage account ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible. You have a few options:

1. Use MPI primitives like gather/bcast/etc. to collect relevant data into a file that can be uploaded by the master task.
2. Use [GetFile from ComputeNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/file/get-from-compute-node) from your client to retrieve the file from the individual nodes. You'll need to write logic to automate this and upload to your storage account.
3. Use a [virtual file system mount](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount) backing into Azure Blob or Files storage, and write directly to files under those mountpoints.